# Custom button shown on simulator but not in an iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm developing an iOS 4 application, using the latest stable SDK (XCode 4.2).

I have a Xib with two custom buttons. These two buttons have the same size and position (one is over the other one). The only different is they have different images.

One user touches the first button, it disappears and then the second button appears. I use this method to do that:

```
- (IBAction)backCardCliked:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5f];
    backCardImage.alpha = 0.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Both, have hidden = NO.

I don't know why it works on simulator (iOS 5), but not in iPhone device (running iOS 4.3.5).

Any clue?

Comment: Today I got the problem, that a UIView was accessable on iOS 5 but not on iOS 4. Try `NSLog("%@",button)` and see if the output is NULL. And btw, is this code a modification? If not, I wouldn't do that like this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How would you do it?

Answer (score 5):

Verify that the name of the images of your buttons are spelled exactly the same way that the name of your image files, including casing. When you have a custom button with a nil image, it is completely transparent.

This different behavior is because the default Mac installation has a *case* ***in****sensitive* file system. The simulator inherits from this environment. The iPhone has a *case sensitive* file system.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the button.opaque is set to NO.